# VHF Radio Sound using SOX

Tags: radio

Firstly I profess to know very little about the science of sound and I am struggling to find anyone who has done this with sox.

I am looking to build a VHF marine radio simulator on Windows and Linux using NodeJS and have identified sox as a possible way to both play and create the VHF radio or walkie-talkie effect. I am generating mp3 from a google speech recognition API and I can play that fine in the simulator with the app.

As an [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FXiKm9Ilb2E)  this is what I would like to achieve.

Does anyone know the sox effects that could be used ? Or any other way ?

Answer (score 1):

I did this using a convolution effect. Basically, I passed a sweep tone through a narrow band FM radio (basically a CB), recorded it and used the result to generate an impulse response that represented the signal path.

This is a blog post that describes the process. Feel free to adapt to your own purposes.

https://www.greensideproductions.com.au/2013/01/04/creating-a-radio-effect-using-a-convolution-filter/

Answer (score 1):

I just went and had a quick read up on sox (I've never heard of it before) and here're my thoughts based on the effects available to you:

Start by using the <kbd>bandpass</kbd> filter to reject a lot of the sound outside 2KHz - 4KHz - This will imitate the small mic and speakers in the chain.

Next use the <kbd>compander</kbd> to reduce the differences between the loud and soft parts of the sound to mimic the compressor in the transceivers.

Finally, use the <kbd>overdrive</kbd> to simulate the small speaker being pushed too hard.

All of these effects are available in sox.

If you can find a way to add a touch of ring modulation (I couldn't see anything in sox but it's my first experience with it) then that will add a lovely touch of atmospheric shift.

Comment: BTW this is where I got my info for available effects: http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html#EFFECTS

Comment: I used something like sox output.mp3 output1.mp3 sinc -n 32767 1000-6000 compand 0.3,1 6:-70,-60,-20 -5 -90 0.2 overdrive 10 and it really works well! Thanks for that.